# Broken hand held shower connector

Tags: shower, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

[image]

[image]

We are looking for a replacement for a fixture that attaches to our hand held shower and hose. It has a female connector that slides on top of the male connector as shown. Could someone tell us what this is called, or where we could purchase a replacement?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm not clear on what this connector is; it it just a hanger for the shower handle, or does it actually carry water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not very clear with your question.

I am assuming that you are looking for the fitting to which the sprayer head attaches, which then drops over the bracket peg in your first picture.

[image]

It is called a swivel connector. They are not "generic", they are specific to the manufacturer of your hand-held shower equipment. This one is from **Alsons**, a very common brand in the U.S.A. and the one I think you may have. Do an internet search for *Alsons Swivel Connector*.